# Date object that gets the current date, but with a time i control which can be converted to unix time

Tags: java, date, unix

I want to be able to request java to get the current date, then I would like to control the time added to that date object and then convert that date object to unix time.

i.e. something like

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Then do this using the `Calendar` object as a converted string

```
String dateString = "Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:40:18 GMT"; //but this 
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy 
hh:mm:ssz");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString );
long unixTime = (long) date.getTime()/1000;
System.out.println(unixTime );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have read your question three times and still do not understand, sorry. I seem to be missing the link between your two code snippets. Are you saying you want the unix time of todays’s date at 23:40:18 GMT (in this example)? From a string containing the desired time on a different date?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are some issues with your date format: You have to use capital `H` for hours when parsing 24-hour times, and I think there was a space missing in front of the timezone `z`.

Using the newer Java time API, you can try this:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:40:18 GMT", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"))
             .with(LocalDate.now())
             .toEpochSecond();
```

The new API is very strict when it come to timezones, you might want to watch out for that. In this implementation, the parsed time defines the timezone (GMT in this example). But maybe you want your local timezone (defined by the virtual machine)? In this case, you can turn it around: `ZonedDateTime.now().with(ZonedDateTime.parse(...).toLocalTime())`.

In your original approach, why do you not continue with the `Calendar`?

```
Date parsedDate = ...;

Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, parsedDate.getHours());
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, parsedDate.getMinutes());
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, parsedDate.getSeconds());
today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

long epoch = today.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

But again, beware of timezones.

Comment: Instead of your two `withXx()` calls, wouldn’t `.with(LocalDate.now())` suffice? `LocalDate` implements the `TemporalAdjuster` interface.

Comment: It’s amazing how many ways the newer date and time classes can be combined, isn’t it?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes of course, thanks! I was looking for exactly that method, but must have missed it... Was wondering why it was so difficult already. And yes, it is indeed cool how many different routes there are to get exactly what you need.

Comment: I would not use `LocalDateTime`. For getting the Unix time you need to know the time zone, and a `LocalDateTime` cannot hold one.